# Using react router to route several paths to the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I got the following routes in my app:

```
<div>
   <Route exact path='/:category' render={() => (
      <Posts/>
   )}/>
   <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
      <Posts/>
   )}/>
</div>
```

Where the second route is just an extension of the first and routes to the same component. How can I combine both routes in one Route tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<Route exact path='/:category?' component={Posts} />` what the question mark does is make the url extension an optional value.